# Cannot download file from mount point in Tomcat application

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, download

I have a tomcat Servlet application which is hosted on more than one tomcat across different machines.
The application have private as well as common files.  Private files are kept on each webapp folder, but common files which are generated on runtime are kept in common mpunt point which is a remote shared folder using nfs. The folder is mounted on each machine and then a simlink is created inside each tomcat webapp folder.

This way file wrote by any one of the tomcat can be accessible to all other one.

Suppose I have 4 tomcats, two per machine.
Then I have  mounted my shared folder on path `/foo/bar/files` on each machine. This is mount from remote shared folder using nfs.
Now a simlink to this folder is created in each application root.

`<Tomcat Home>/webapp/<app context>/files -> /foo/bar/files`

When ever user upload some file, we place it in this folder. This make that file available for all other tomcat.

No my problem is when I write file to this folder, it happens successfully. But when ever user try to download the file, it gives `Error code 404`.
I tried direct url. `<host>:<port>/<context>/files/foo.csv`. then too I am getting 404. 
I even try to stream the file through Servlet and I get stuck download and there is no IO error on server side.

I am using Redhat.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you configured allowLinking="true" for that web application? Exactly how to configure that will depend on your Tomcat version (which you haven't told us yet).

Comment: yes. done that and it working.  I forgot to mention it here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding allowLinking="true" to server.xml's  tag solved the issue.